# Требуется ли «после» отделять запятой?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Пос­ле, я поп­ро­бова­ла по­шеве­лить ру­ками и но­гами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**После**](http://endic.ru/kuzhecov/Posle-32293.html) в этом предложении — это наречие, имеющее значение ***спустя некоторое время, позже, потом.*** Попробовала (когда?) после — запятая не требуется.

**После я попробовала пошевелить руками и ногами.**
*После я взглянула на маму и отрицательно покачала головой* (Л. Слюсарева).
*После она отвернулась и громко крикнула* (Д. Хмурый).

Теоретически, конечно, можно придумать контекст, в котором слово "после" отделяется от последующей части (но все равно это будет наречие).

[Предположим, что диалог происходит в больнице.]
— Я помогу тебе умыться и переодеться.
— После. Я попробовала пошевелить руками и ногами.